# tensorflow : cost function output 0 in some input data

Tags: tensorflow

hi Im studying machine learning.
I tried softmax classification with neural net.
In learning progress, label 1,2 is good learning state.
But at label 3, cost output is always 0.0.
I think i`m not fully understand about neural net.

I,m trying to make learning model.
input_sequence_length = 3, output_class = 3

0 <= input <= 2  result = 1

3 <= input <= 5  result = 2

6 <= input <= 8  result = 3

please let me know what i missing.

below source code is partial.

---

input data (0~2 -> 1, 3~5 -> 2, 6~8 -> 3) 1,2,3 = label

```
0   2   0   1
5   4   5   2
7   6   8   3
2   2   0   1
5   3   4   2
7   6   7   3
```

output

```
1. input X : [[0, 2, 0]] Y(label) : [[1]]
cost : 1.25544  hypothesis : [0.30000001, 0.28, 0.41]

2. input X : [[5, 4, 5]] Y(label) : [[2]]
cost : 1.10084 hypothesis : [0.31, 0.36000001, 0.33000001]

3. input X : [[7, 6, 8]] Y(label) : [[3]]
cost : 0.0  hypothesis : [0.28, 0.25, 0.47999999]

4. input X : [[2, 2, 0]] Y(label) : [[1]]
cost : 1.22364  hypothesis : [0.27000001, 0.28999999, 0.44]

5. input X : [[5, 3, 4]] Y(label) : [[2]]
cost : 0.961203  hypothesis : [0.30000001, 0.31999999, 0.38]

6. input X : [[7, 6, 7]] Y(label) : [[3]]
cost : 0.0 hypothesis : [0.27000001, 0.23999999, 0.49000001]
```

source code

```
batch_size = 1
input_sequence_length = 3 
output_sequence_length = 1
input_num_classes = 9
output_num_classes = 3
hidden_size = 12
learning_rate = 0.1


with tf.name_scope("placeholder") as scope:

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, input_sequence_length], name="x_input")
    X_one_hot = tf.one_hot(X, input_num_classes)

    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, output_sequence_length], name="y_input")  # 1
    Y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(Y, output_num_classes)  # one hot
    Y_one_hot = tf.reshape(Y_one_hot, [-1, output_num_classes])

    X_one_hot = tf.reshape(X_one_hot, [batch_size , input_sequence_length * input_num_classes])
    outputs = tf.to_float(X_one_hot)


with tf.name_scope("Layer_1") as scope:

    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_sequence_length * input_num_classes, **strong text**hidden_size]), name='weight1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_size]), name='bias1')

    outputs = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(outputs, W1) + b1)


with tf.name_scope("Layer_2") as scope:

    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_size, output_num_classes]), name='weight2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_num_classes]), name='bias2')

    logits = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(outputs, W2) + b2)


with tf.name_scope("hypothesis") as scope:

    hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

with tf.name_scope("cost") as scope:

    # Cross entropy cost/loss
    cost_i = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y_one_hot)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost_i)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.one_hot`'s first argument (`indices`) is zero-indexed.

`tf.one_hot(3,3)` will produce `[0, 0, 0]`, leading to a cross entropy error of 0.

Comment: thank you ! I solved problem.  problem was one_hot  function miss understanding